# How do I create a Ruby GraphQL InputObject instance from a Hash?

Tags: ruby, testing, graphql

I have a `GraphQL::Schema::InputObject` subclass that I pass around inside my Rails server's GraphQL mutation handler. I've separated out some of the parts of the code as separate units to test and would like to create an instance of this object in test. How can I do this?

My subclass looks like this:

```rb
class Foo < GraphQL::Schema::InputObject
  argument :bar, Int, required: true
end
```

I peeked inside the graphql-ruby tests and [saw there's a constructor that take a Hash](https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby/blob/6fc8bea4ba9093bfa81da148f4856ba0b5e89014/spec/graphql/schema/input_object_spec.rb#L301-L307), so I tried:

```rb
Foo.new({bar: 42}, context: OpenStruct.new(), defaults_used: Set.new())
```

but I get back:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass)
```

I'm using graphql-ruby 1.9.9.

Answer (score 0):

[Reading the tests more closely](https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby/blob/6fc8bea4ba9093bfa81da148f4856ba0b5e89014/spec/graphql/schema/input_object_spec.rb#L297) revealed that before you can call the constructor, you must first call [`to_graphql`](https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby/blob/6fc8bea4ba9093bfa81da148f4856ba0b5e89014/lib/graphql/schema/input_object.rb#L110-L124) (documented in [Extending the GraphQL-Ruby Type Definition System](https://graphql-ruby.org/type_definitions/extensions.html)). This method appears to bake out some schema/metaprogramming data. Adding this line before the `new` call makes it work as I expect:

```rb
Foo.to_graphql
```

However, the constructor doesn't appear to run any of the type coercions for the arguments: values are returned from the accessor methods verbatim.